# Managed custom permission B2BCommerceAdmin is not accessible

Tags: managed-package, custom-permission

I installed the package B2B Commerce for Visualforce in a developer org. I follow the instructions in "Salesforce B2B Commerce for Visualforce" help page. The instructions say to add the "Access B2B Commerce Admin Settings" permission set.

This permission set adds the custom permission "B2BCommerceAdmin" which comes with the managed package.

When I attempt to add the permission set, I have the following message :

[image]

I attempted to add this permission to users having the "Salesforce" license type. The Permission Set has no license assigned. But another managed Permission Set could be assigned succesfully to those users.

I tried to add the Custom Permission manually : it is even not displayed in the list of available custom permissions.
I created a Custom Permission : it is visible.

I guess that it is possible to access and add managed custom permissions. So what could be the reason of this invisibility ?

The Developer Org is a bit old (12/2021). Could it be a clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** : the Organization is old and has been created without the "B2B Commerce" Permission Set license. After creating a fresh developer org, following instructions on "Salesforce B2B Commerce for Visualforce", the Permissions Set could be assigned succesfully.

This took a long time to resolve because the Permission Set doesn't show any license, giving no indication about the kind of Profile it should be assigned to.